# Android app doesn't get any push notification from AWS SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have 2 apps. One is a sample application from AWS Mobile Hub and the other is a test project for testing the AWS SNS push notifications. I integrated the push services from the sample app into my test app, but for some reason it doesn't work, it doesn't get any push notifications from AWS SNS.

The things I've copied are:

The package `com.amazonaws.mobile` and all of its files.

The libraries from the module's `build.gradle` file.

The permissions, receiver and service attributes from the manifest file.

`PushListenerService` class.

For some reason I still don't get any push notifications. Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: Have you tried following the AWS Mobile Hub's new integration instructions? http://imgur.com/a/s9BaW

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following the AWS Mobile Hub's new integration instructions? imgur.com/a/s9BaW

Just listing a few things that seem to be missing from your list:

You need to add **Gradle dependencies** in `build.gradle` (versions may vary)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.18'
```

Specify the **Google Services Version** to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Register an **Intent Receiver for GCM** to listen to GCM notfications

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="{com.yourapp.package}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name=".PushListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**Register the device** to receive push notifications

```
final PushManager pushManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient()
    .getPushManager();

pushManager.registerDevice();

// if registration succeeded.
if (pushManager.isRegistered()) {
    pushManager.setPushEnabled(enabled);
} else {
    // ... handle error, likely due to no network available ...
}

final PushManager pushManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient()
    .getPushManager();

pushManager.registerDevice();

// if registration succeeded.
if (pushManager.isRegistered()) {
    pushManager.setPushEnabled(enabled);
} else {
    // ... handle error, likely due to no network available ...
}
```

**Register for topics**

```
final PushManager pushManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient()
    .getPushManager();

pushManager.subscribeToTopic(pushManager.getDefaultTopic());
```

Comment: I did all of the above but I still don't receive any push notifications from the app... By the way, when I've added the library `play-services-plus` instead of the `play-services` library that I already had in my app, it said that it can't find `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver`. Do you know maybe why is it like this?

Comment: Try to add:
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
Those libs worked for me with no problems! @IdoNaveh